# Defining method in Ruby with equals

Tags: ruby, syntax

Being new to Ruby, I'm having trouble *explaining to myself* the behavior around method definitions within Ruby.

The example is noted below...

```
class Foo
  def do_something(action)
    action.inspect
  end
  def do_something_else=action 
    action.inspect
  end
end

?> f.do_something("drive")
=> "\"drive\""

?> f.do_something_else=("drive")
=> "drive"
```

The first example is self explanatory. What Im trying to understand is the behavior of the second example. Other than what looks to be one producing a string literal and the other is not, what is actually happening? Why would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally, `do_something` is a getter, and `do_something=` is a setter.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end
```

is equivalent to

```
class Foo
  def bar
    @bar
  end

  def bar=(value)
    @bar = value
  end
end
```

To answer your question about the difference in behavior, methods that end in `=` always return the right hand side of the expression. In this case returning `action`, not `action.inspect`.

```
class Foo
  def do_something=(action)
    "stop"
  end
end

?> f = Foo.new
?> f.do_something=("drive")
=> "drive"
```

Comment: @Erik Peterson Is the `=` symbolic such as `?` Could I in theory ignore the passed in value? `@bar = "something random"`?

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, you could. Probably not too many cases where that's a good idea. However, you cannot change the return value, it will always be the right hand side. Also, you'll find it difficult/impossible to define a method that ends in `=` and takes multiple arguments.

Comment: @ErikPeterson So in your example the fact that you placed `stop` as the return value has no bearing on the _actual_ return value, which in your example is `drive` since that was the passed in value. That behavior however is not the case for my first example. With that, this means that the `=` is driving that behavior and it is not _convention_ per se as is the `?`. Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: @AaronMcIver: That's correct. The `=` methods have _semantic behavior_, `?` methods returning `true` or `false` is a _convention_.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the party, here, but this answer isn't strictly correct. The _return value_ of the `do_something=` _method_ is exactly what it looks like it should be, that is to say, `"stop"`. You can verify this by calling `f.send(:do_something=,"drive")`, the return value will be `"stop"`. However, `f.do_something = "drive"`, as an _expression_, _evaluates_ to `"drive"`, regardless of the _return value_ of the method. In other words, it's not the return value of setter methods, the evaluation of assignment expressions, that always resolves to the right-hand-side of the expression.

Answer (score 10):

Both of your methods are actually being defined and called *as methods*. Quite a lot of things in Ruby can be defined as methods, even the operators such as `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`. Ruby allows methods to have three special *notational suffixes*. I made that phrase up all by myself. What I mean by *notational suffixes* is that the thing on the end of the method will indicate how that method is *supposed* to work.

### Bang!

The first *notational suffix* is `!`. This indicates that the method is supposed to be *destructive*, meaning that it modifies the object that it's called on. Compare the output of these two scripts:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.map { |x| x * x }
a
```

And:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.map! { |x| x * x }
a
```

There's a one character difference between the two scripts, but they operate differently! The first one will still go through each element in the array and perform the operation inside the block, but the object in `a` will still be the same `[1,2,3]` that you started with.

In the second example, however, the `a` at the end will instead be `[1, 4, 9]` because `map!` modified the object in place!

### Query

The second *notational suffix* is `?`, and that indicates that a method is used to query an object about something, and means that the method is supposed to return `true`, `false` or in some [extreme circumstances](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5329), `nil`.

Now, note that the method *doesn't have to* return `true` or `false`... it's just that it'd be very nice if it did that!

Proof:

```
def a?
  true
end

def b?
  "moo"
end
```

Calling `a?` will return `true`, and calling `b?` will return "moo". So there, that's query methods. The methods that *should* return `true` or `false` but sometimes can return other things because some developers don't like other developers.

### Setters!

**NOW** we get to the meat of your (paraphrased) question: *what does `=` mean on the end of a method?*

That usually indicates that a method is going to set a particular value, as [Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12811965/15245) already outlined before I finished typing this essay of an answer.

However, it *may not* set one, just like the query methods *may not* return `true` or `false`. It's just convention.

You can call that setter method like this also:

```
foo.something_else="value"
```

Or (my favourite):

```
foo.something_else = "value"
```

In theory, you can actually ignore the passed in value, just like you can completely ignore any arguments passed into any method:

```
def foo?(*args)
  "moo"
end

>> foo?(:please, :oh, :please, :why, :"won't", :you, :use, :these, :arguments, :i, :got, :just, :for, :you, :question_mark?)
=> "moo"
```

Ruby supports all three syntaxes for setter methods, although it's very rare to see the one you used!

Well, I hope this answer's been roughly educational and that you understand more things about Ruby now. Enjoy!

Comment: This was very educational. It's the _convention_ over actual behavior that was confusing me. It seems that the `=` is not only _convention_ but also behavior as Eric pointed out, the passed in value will **always** be the returned value, regardless of the activities that take place within the method itself.

Comment: Apologies, the above comment was a question; not necessarily a statement. To clarify, would it be accurate to describe the `=` notation as `convention` but also `behavior` due to not being able to change the right hand side of the expression as the return value, regardless of what is done within the method?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define a return value for assignment methods. The return value is always the same as the value passed in, so that assignment chains (`x = y = z = 3`) will always work.

Typically, you would omit the brackets when you invoke the method, so that it behaves like a property:

```
my_value = f.do_something= "drive"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def do_something_else=action 
  action.inspect
end
```

This defines a setter method, so do_something_else appears as though we are initializing a attribute. So the value initialized is directly passed,